# Как перенести игрока с одной сцены на другую? Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно реализовать перенос игрока на другую сцену, Работаю в 2д.

Игрок - это префаб у которого есть несколько полей, которые нужно перенести с одной сцены на другую. При старте 1 сцены все значения должны стоять по умолчанию.

Пробовал делать через scriptable object, но он работал криво (со scriptable object я работал впервые)

P.s заранее спасибо!

Comment: Сохраняй данные перед загрузкой сцены, загружай после загрузки сцены. Все это элементарно гуглится, зачем плодить однотипные вопросы, ответ на которые находится на первой строчке гугла. `Пробовал делать через scriptable object, но он работал криво` как криво? Что не работало? Добавляй код, если хочешь, чтобы тебе посоветовали.

Comment: Можно ничего не переносить, а сделать уровень сценой внутри сцены, а персонаж игрока остаётся на основной.